# href link in parent element of submenu class

Tags: list, navigation, href

I have a simple navigation bar:

```
<div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
             <ul class="nav">
                 <li class="submenu">                        
                         <a href="index.php">
                            <i a href="index.php" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Idmancilar
                            <span class="caret pull-right" href="index.php"></span>
                         </a>
                         <ul>
                            <li><a href="player_requests.php">Qeydiyyat sorgulari</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                   
                <li><a href="calendar.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Mesqciler</a></li>
                <li><a href="stats.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Klublar</a></li>
                <li><a href="tables.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Yarislar</a></li>
                <li><a href="editors.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Qeydiyyat sorgulari</a></li>  
                <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Logout</a></li>                   
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
```

When I open the submenu the player_requests is opened, but from there I can not navifate back to the parent index.php page. When I click on element the span and submenu are opened again and no redirection to the required index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the fact that you have invalid HTML.
**Only** the `<a>`, `<area>`, `<base>` and `<link>` tags can have the `href` attribute.
Both `<i a href="index.php" ... >` and `<span ... href="index.php">` are invalid.

You'll need to remove `href` from both your `<i>` and your `<span>` tags,
as can be seen in the following:

```html
<div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="submenu">
      <a href="index.php">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Idmancilar
        <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="player_requests.php">Qeydiyyat sorgulari</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="calendar.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Mesqciler</a></li>
    <li><a href="stats.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Klublar</a></li>
    <li><a href="tables.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Yarislar</a></li>
    <li><a href="editors.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Qeydiyyat sorgulari</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```